# Python 3.6 module appscript install error

Tags: python, xlwings, sourceforge-appscript

I wanted to install the module `xlwings`, and one of its dependencies is `appscript`. So when I do:

```
pip3.6 install xlwings
```

I get the following error:

```
Collecting xlwings
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/cf/c4e5ba995c6440fff3f6e846ba0aa92481d8d5c54c27860a324df525802b/xlwings-0.15.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from xlwings) (5.4.8)
Collecting appscript>=1.0.1 (from xlwings)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/0b/0ad06b376b2119c6c02a6d214070c8528081ed868bf82853d4758bf942eb/appscript-1.0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: appscript, xlwings
  Running setup.py install for appscript ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4m/q2rj8ww90ms0jwg7zv4ldwqh0000gn/T/pip-install-t_le314z/appscript/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/4m/q2rj8ww90ms0jwg7zv4ldwqh0000gn/T/pip-record-7kas7ahn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    Distribution option extra_path is deprecated. See issue27919 for details.
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    copying appscript_3x/lib/mactypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    copying appscript_3x/lib/osax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/aemsend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/findapp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/aemconnect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/typewrappers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/kae.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/aemreference.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/aemcodecs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    copying appscript_3x/lib/aem/mactypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/aem
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/keywordwrapper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/referencerenderer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/terminologyparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/reservedkeywords.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/reference.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/defaultterminology.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/terminology.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    copying appscript_3x/lib/appscript/genericreference.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript
    running build_ext
    building 'aem.ae' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript_3x
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript_3x/ext
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c appscript_3x/ext/ae.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/appscript_3x/ext/ae.o -DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4
    In file included from appscript_3x/ext/ae.c:15:
    In file included from appscript_3x/ext/ae.h:26:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:34:10: fatal error: 'CarbonSound/CarbonSound.h' file not found
    #include <CarbonSound/CarbonSound.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4m/q2rj8ww90ms0jwg7zv4ldwqh0000gn/T/pip-install-t_le314z/appscript/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/4m/q2rj8ww90ms0jwg7zv4ldwqh0000gn/T/pip-record-7kas7ahn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4m/q2rj8ww90ms0jwg7zv4ldwqh0000gn/T/pip-install-t_le314z/appscript/
```

I'm using Jupyter Notebook, and the notebook is running Python 3.6 so I want to specifically install `appscript` and `xlwings` on 3.6.

My OS is macOS Mojave 10.14.1.

The error code says the problem is with clang, so here is my clang version:

```
$clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Can anyone possibly shed some light please?

Comment: I have the same issue; can you also provide some comments on the related Github issue that is created for this problem? It is at: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/988

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
the `appscript` package is now available as binary wheels from pypi. Simply do `pip install appscript` or `pip install xlwings` again.

**Previous answer**:

Make sure you have the XCode command line tools installed when installing with pip as pointed out on http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html#dependencies

If you want things to be easier, use the Anaconda distribution: It does not require the XCode command line tools.

Comment: When I go to the Environment tab in my anaconda navigator, both of my "base (root)" and "anaconda" environment says appscript and xlwings are both installed. Although I try to import, it says the module doesn't exist. Any idea?

Comment: Try to uninstall with pip and reinstall it with conda

Comment: I did `pip uninstall appscript` and I got the following message: `Cannot uninstall 'appscript'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: I would try in a new conda env from scratch.

Comment: the appscript package is now available as wheels from pypi. Simply do `pip install appscript` or `pip install xlwings` again.